# spark is launched dir is working but spark-shell is not getting lanuch getting error 'spark-shell' is not recognized

Tags: shell, apache-spark, spark-shell

[cmd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZzAd.png)I have done everything as instructed but still not able to launch spark-shell

dir is working

I have placed all downloaded files as instructed but spark-shell is not working.

C:\Users\admin>cd c:\spark

c:\spark>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BCEB-22EE

Directory of c:\spark

11/05/2019  05:19 PM              .
11/05/2019  05:19 PM              ..
11/05/2019  04:59 PM       230,091,034 spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
               1 File(s)    230,091,034 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  180,582,641,664 bytes free

c:\spark>spark-shell
'spark-shell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\admin>cd c:\spark

c:\spark>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BCEB-22EE

Directory of c:\spark

11/05/2019  05:19 PM              .
11/05/2019  05:19 PM              ..
11/05/2019  04:59 PM       230,091,034 spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
               1 File(s)    230,091,034 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  180,582,641,664 bytes free

c:\spark>spark-shell
'spark-shell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.[cmd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGl6X.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the contents of **spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz**. (maybe with winzip?)
2. This will result in a directory probably something like **spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7**.  Inside that directory there will be one called **bin** cd into that as well
3. In bin you will find the spark-shell scripts

Comment: that's strange for me too. as per the instructor video it's supposed to be zipped file. but when I downloaded it was just a single file

Comment: a zipped or tar gzipped file is a single file, where the contents of all files are compressed and merged into a single binary file.  You have to uncompress it first.

Comment: it's not a zipped file. It was a normal file.

Comment: spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz -- it **tar** archive file that was also **gzip**ed hence the **tgz** extension

Comment: You are right I have downloaded the RAR file but did not install it.. In instructor video rar installation was missing. After installing RAR my file started showing its a zip file earlier it was showing unzipped. after that it got fixed.